# Registering windows network path as local texmf directory in MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, installing, windows, texmf

I would like to add a Windows UNC network path (e.g. `\\server\path\to\local\texmf`) as local texmf directory to my MiKTeX installation. I know how to add a path that has a local drive letter (e.g. `C:\path\to\local\texmf`), since this is described well here ([Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)) and in the MiKTeX docs (http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html).

I could bind the UNC path (or part of it) to a local drive letter. However, I would like not to do so and add the UNC path directly.

Is there a way to do it? How? Thanks.

Comment: You could try it with the command line command `initexmf --register-root XXXX`. If it doesn't work, you could make a feature request.

Comment: Good to know ...;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows UNC network paths can be added as MiKTeX local texmf directories using the Windows command line.

To add a UNC path, start a console (open start menu, type `cmd` and choose `cmd.exe`). If you want to add the UNC path as administrator (i.e. for all users on your machine), be sure to start the console as administrator (in the start menu, after typing `cmd`, right-click on `cmd.exe`, choose `Run as administrator` and approve the Windows User Account Control request).

In the console, type

```
initexmf --register-root \\server\path
```

or, when adding for all users,

```
initexmf --admin --register-root \\server\path
```

Be sure to refresh the file name database subsequently either using the GUI or typing `initexmf --update-fndb` or `initexmf --admin --update-fndb`, respectively. If you have installed any fonts, also run `initexmf --mkmaps` or `initexmf --admin --mkmaps`.

Note 1: More information on the process is given at [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Note 2: More information on initexmf is available at http://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html.